# Jupyter Notebook Stuck In Runtime

Tags: sql, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've an assignment where I have to write SQL queries for certain questions, however, when I hit run for certain questions (in cells) the Jupyter notebook is stuck in run time i.e it is neither executing not throwing an error .

Please refer to the attached screenshots and notebook for further details

I tried restarting the Jupyter notebook and my computer nothing seem to be working.

[image]

This is one of the queries (for 3rd question) for which the jupyter notebook is getting stuck (I've imported all the necessary libs) :

```py
Act = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT a.NAME FROM Person a
Inner Join M_cast b
ON LTRIM(a.PID) = LTRIM(b.PID)
Inner Join Movie c
ON c.MID = b.MID
WHERE c.year NOT BETWEEN 1970 AND 1990""",connection)
```

Note : I'm using `LTRIM` because there're spaces to the left of MIDs an PIDs, without LTRIM the Inner Join returns null

Please check the drive link for the notebook, `sqlitefile` and schema of the DBfile if you need to replicate.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HaCW9IbgX6ho-QnzTKBELu4HlVKlIKaL?usp=sharing

I checked all types of forums, I'm not sure why I'm facing this issue.

Comment: It is executing, just it can not finish, e.g. due to query result not being found (or an infinite loop, in another case).

Comment: Yes, but in this case the table in the batabase file are not that large and I'm also not using comlicated joins that would result in the notebook getting stuck